# error -1 al enviar datos a un servidor de php myadmin desde arduino

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, arduino

al tratar de enviar la url por php a un servidor de phpmyadmin me da un error en el monitor serial code:-1

al investigar supe que ese error significa que se rechazó la conexión con el servidor pero no entiendo por que pueda ser pense que quiza seria por tema de firewall pero no se como solucionarlo

Answer (score 0):

- Si tienes Windows ve a propiedades de sistemas, luego administrador de dispositivos, y allí encontraras y podrás configurar la conexion serial del arduino. Debe ser la misma que configuraste en arduino.